# How do I delete a Windows partition?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, partition, startup

I tried to install Windows 10 with Boot Camp and I got an error. When I tried to reboot my MacBook and held Alt, I have two partitions: MacintoshHD and Windows. If I click on Windows I have a blue Windows screen with "Recovery". So how I can delete this partition?

Answer (score 1):

1. Close all open applications;
2. Open Boot Camp Assistant (click `Continue`);
3. Select `Remove Windows 10 or later version`;
4. Click `Restore` if your Mac has one internal disk, otherwise select the Windows disk and select `Restore disk to a single macOS partition`, and then press `Continue`.

It is recommanded to do a backup before doing so.

Comment: I know this, but boot camp not detected Win10. Programs dont detected this partition.

Comment: Ok, you  should have included that in your question. Since I don't have this issue I don't know personally what you can do... Except if you haven't tried with Disk Utility.

Comment: Have you tried that?

Comment: I removed it by rEFInd.

Comment: If it is done, post an Answer explaining what you did, in order to help other people who might have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Start all over again . This may help you to delete the partition.